# How to apply different content on the same cell identifier on UICollectionView in Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, uicollectionview

Is this code make sense to you? I am trying to put different content on the same cell identifier which's triggered on `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:`:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    println("bosen kelima")
    if (collectionView == self.filterCollectionView) {//here
        println("First Content")
        let cell = self.filterCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("FILTER_CELL", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FilterThumbnailCell
        var filterThumbnail = self.filterThumbnails![indexPath.row] // this one through bottom of this function will be deleted and moved to "didSelectItemAtIndexPath"
        var filterThumbnailTwo = self.secondFilterThumbnails![indexPath.row]

        cell.filterTitle.text = filterThumbnail.filterName
        //Lazy Loading
            if filterThumbnail.filteredThumbnail != nil {
                cell.imageView.image = filterThumbnail.filteredThumbnail
            }
            else {
                cell.imageView.image = filterThumbnail.originalThumbnail
                //filterThumbnail is a class instance
                filterThumbnail.generateThumbnail({ (image) -> Void in
                    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? FilterThumbnailCell {
                        cell.imageView.image = image
                    }
                })
            }
            if filterThumbnailTwo.filteredThumbnail != nil {
                cell.imageView.image = filterThumbnailTwo.filteredThumbnail
            }

            else  {
                cell.imageView.image = filterThumbnailTwo.originalThumbnail
                //filterThumbnail is a class instance
                filterThumbnailTwo.generateThumbnail({ (image) -> Void in
                    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? FilterThumbnailCell {
                        cell.imageView.image = image
                    }
                })
            }


        return cell
    }

}
```

if it doesn't make sense, can you give me solution? I've been looking the solution for almost a week but still no clue

Answer (score 0):

What different content?

If you have the same Cell type with different states, you will need a Bool (2 states) or an enum for 2 or more states.

You then check the state of the cell and do what you need to. You also need to update the cell state from the correct object as needed.

Comment: Can you give me the code example please or at least show me how to make a bool? I am sorry I am new in swift @helium3